# What are the LaTeX typefacing standards for subscripts in physics regarding coordinate axes?

Tags: pdftex, typography, typefaces

Say we have the following kinematic equation:

y<sub>f</sub> = y<sub>i</sub> + v<sub>i<sub>y</sub></sub>t + ½a<sub>y</sub>t<sup>2</sup>

Where y<sub>i</sub> and y<sub>f</sub> represent initial and final displacements, v<sub>i<sub>y</sub></sub> represents an initial velocity along the y-axis, and a<sub>y</sub> represents an acceleration along the y-axis.

I know the general consensus for this situation says that only variables should be in italics (among many other specific cases). So the i and j subscripts should certainly be upright. However, there is a [typefacing document from NIST](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/typefaces.pdf) that italicizes a z-coordinate at the bottom of the first page. It's not exactly clear if this coordinate is italicized due to the value of omega changing as one moves along the z-axis, or if this references the z-axis itself.

So the question is... which way is correct? Should the y subscript in the equation above be in italics? Or upright?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately this is really off topic. Notation conventions are very field specific and are not really TeX related unless you're asking how to achieve them with LaTeX (as opposed to asking what they should/shouldn't be.)

Comment: See https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/AMS-StyleGuide-online.pdf section 12.0 and pls modify your question to comply with the site rules so is not closed.